# Centering A 4-column Div In Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, center

I'm new to bootstrap and having trouble. I've searched for an hour now trying to figure out how I would get a div I've made (which is purposed to be a link) to display in the center of a page but have had no success. Below is my HTML and CSS code, if you could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="categories.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Categories</title>
    </head>


    <body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="category col-md-4 col-centered">
                <a class="link" href="http://google.com">TEST</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.category {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
    background: #09719B;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

.category:hover {
    background-color: #064661;
}

.category a{
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

.category:hover a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You are incorrectly using Bootstrap. Bootstrap has it's own ways to center columns and using your own class for something that is already built-in is reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your categories.css to after the bootstrap css. like below. This override the bootstrap styles.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="categories.css">
```

Refer this https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.3.2

another way use bootstrap class `.col-md-offset-4`

Comment: ahhh, of course it was something silly like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use class:

```
category col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2
```

instead of `category col-md-4 col-centered`
which will make div 4/12 i.e 1/3

of the parent div if screen size is `<=md`.

here's the filddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dx6yd3rn/2/)

Comment: I should clarify, I don't want the div to take up all 12 columns, just the middle 4 or 8 or whatever I specify.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.col-md-offset-4` to center your `.col-md-4`. If you are using default bootstrap then your grid has 12 columns. Your div takes 4 columns so offsetting it by 4 columns will make it start at 4th column and end at 8th which will be the same as centering.

I highly encourage you to read [Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), especially [offsetting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) section.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eco9n54b/)